# Oninvalid doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function getExerciseTitle() {
  var exerciseTitle = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'getExerciseTitle form-group form-control required',
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'getExerciseTitle',
    'id': 'getExerciseTitle',
    'placeholder': 'Exercise title',
    'required': true,
    'oninvalid': this.setCustomValidity('Your exercise would like to have a title!'),
    'oninput': this.setCustomValidity('')
  });

  return exerciseTitle;
}
```

Now, whenever I click submit without a title, it does not show the required message. It doesn't submit either, so that works, but the border just turns red instead of throwing in the required message aswell.

Comment: Have you determined what the point of failure is? In other words, is the event handler called at all, or is the `this` reference not what you expect it to be

Comment: I believe the this reference. Because it doesn't submit, but doesn't throw in any message either. I think even with "required" statement is a fake one, because I have a script that stops the ajax call from sending the form when the value of the function is empty.

Comment: I suspect any `'on...'` property expects a function not a string

Comment: The next error will be thrown in when I take away the string parts of so it becomes a function: Uncaught TypeError: this.setCustomValidity is not a function